# How to fit my lightning page to screen height?

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components, css, slds

I have a lightning page (accessed via Lightning Component tab) which display a custom search box and a lighting map component. The idea is I would like the map to fill the screen (minus the search box and the salesforce header).

Currently, the map goes past the screen fold (by about 150px) which makes the UX a little poor. I am trying to use slds-grid and flex to have the page fit the screen but this doesn't appear to work.

Here is my html mark up on the page:

```
<template>
        <div class="slds-card" style="height: 100%;">
            <div class="slds-grid slds-is-relative slds-grid_vertical slds-card__body slds-card__body_inner" style="height: 100%">
                <c-search-bar onchoicemade={handleSearch}></c-search-bar>
                <div class="" style="flex: 1 1 auto;">
                    <lightning-map map-markers={mapMarkers} list-view="hidden"></lightning-map>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </template>
```

Can someone point me in the right direction to have this display correctly?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know your whole setup but either way easiest implementation is as you said, probably grid. Grid setup for one component below another in your case would be:

```
<div class="slds-grid slds-grid_vertical">
  <div class="slds-col">
    <c-search-bar onchoicemade={handleSearch}></c-custom-lookup>
  </div>
  <div class="slds-col">
    <lightning-map map-markers={mapMarkers} list-view="hidden"></lightning-map>
  </div>
</div>
```

With Card it would be probably something like:

```
<article class="slds-card">
  <div class="slds-card__body slds-card__body_inner">
      <div class="slds-col">
        <c-search-bar onchoicemade={handleSearch}></c-custom-lookup>
      </div>
      <div class="slds-col">
        <lightning-map map-markers={mapMarkers} list-view="hidden"></lightning-map>
      </div></div>
</article>
```

[image: Example]

Comment: Don’t I need to use flex to get the elements to stretch the whole page?

Comment: Nope you do not need to. I've added example screenshot which includes the same component in two places on lightinng page. It is automatically resizing to max width. I've added some input field in exchange for your search component

Comment: So in my page, the component takes the whole page, instead of columns... and similar to your page on the left... it scrolls paste the fold.